# Python 3.4: editing all lines in txt file

Tags: python-3.x

I have a text with the following information.

```
1000045|NICHOLAS FINANCIAL INC|SC 13D/A|2015-04-24|edgar/data/1000045/0000897069-15-000319.txt
1000045|NICHOLAS FINANCIAL INC|SC 13G/A|2015-05-29|edgar/data/1000045/0001193125-15-206657.txt
1000045|NICHOLAS FINANCIAL INC|SC 13G|2015-05-08|edgar/data/1000045/0001144204-15-028845.txt
1000097|KINGDON CAPITAL MANAGEMENT, L.L.C.|13F-HR|2015-05-15|edgar/data/1000097/0000919574-15-004506.txt
1000097|KINGDON CAPITAL MANAGEMENT, L.L.C.|SC 13G/A|2015-05-28|edgar/data/1000097/0000919574-15-004670.txt
1000097|KINGDON CAPITAL MANAGEMENT, L.L.C.|SC 13G/A|2015-06-08|edgar/data/1000097/0000919574-15-004791.txt
1000097|KINGDON CAPITAL MANAGEMENT, L.L.C.|SC 13G|2015-05-26|edgar/data/1000097/0000919574-15-004632.txt
1000097|KINGDON CAPITAL MANAGEMENT, L.L.C.|SC 13G|2015-06-08|edgar/data/1000097/0000919574-15-004793.txt
1000152|WESTERN INTERNATIONAL SECURITIES, INC.|X-17A-5|2015-04-16|edgar/data/1000152/9999999997-15-008305.txt
1000177|NORDIC AMERICAN TANKERS Ltd|20-F/A|2015-04-29|edgar/data/1000177/0000919574-15-003778.txt
1000177|NORDIC AMERICAN TANKERS Ltd|6-K|2015-04-30|edgar/data/1000177/0000919574-15-003819.txt
1000180|SANDISK CORP|10-Q|2015-04-30|edgar/data/1000180/0001000180-15-000027.txt
1000180|SANDISK CORP|4|2015-05-27|edgar/data/1000180/0001242648-15-000023.txt
1000180|SANDISK CORP|8-K|2015-04-15|edgar/data/1000180/0001000180-15-000023.txt
1000180|SANDISK CORP|ARS|2015-05-04|edgar/data/1000180/9999999997-15-009621.txt
1000180|SANDISK CORP|DEF 14A|2015-04-27|edgar/data/1000180/0001047469-15-003972.txt
```

I need to edit the information and return each line with the following format effectively deleting before 'edgar'

```
edgar/data/1000180/0001047469-15-003972.txt
```

Comment: Could you show to us what you already tried? Are you aware of all functions that could help you to do it very easely (python functions for handling strings, CSV module coming from the standard library, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way without importing any libraries:

Assuming that this data is stored in a file called `data.txt`:

```
lines = []

with open('data.txt') as data:
    for line in data:
        lines.append(line.rstrip()) # rstrip() removes the newline character

for i in range(len(lines)):
    lines[i] = 'edgar' + lines[i].split('edgar')[1]
```

Comment: IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option (Python 2.x or 3.x):

```
results = []

with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        results.append(line.rstrip().split('|')[4]) # append to results the 4th element of the line
print(results)
```

This will loop through the file by line, split on the pipe character, and take the 4th element (the part you want).

It assumes in input file called `file.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what ended up working for me.

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    data = str.splitlines(f.read())
    for eachLine in data:
        print(eachLine.split('|')[-1])
```